# Русский язык в консоли Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio

Как сделать русский язык в консоли Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express? Вместо русских букв выводятся крякозябры.

Comment: @dr_kraken, подобные вопросы здесь многократно обсуждались.

Наверное, проще всего посмотреть не них, задав в гугле вопрос

     site:hashcode.ru windows кракозябры


Получите, например, http://hashcode.ru/questions/70089

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
```

или просто

```
setlocale(0, "");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я имел ввиду настройку где-то подправить, или что-то типа того. А вы предлагаете каждый раз в исх. код проги вставлять данную конструкцию. Не удобно.

Comment: @dr_kraken действительно, зачем программе корректно работать, можно же на хосте настройки подкрутить

Comment: @Flike На каком хосте? Я имел ввиду в Visual Studio настройки подправить, если они конечно же есть.

Comment: Вопрос решился подобным образом:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

  puts("Привет, мир!");

  return 0;
}

Comment: Попробуйте добавить перед `return 0;`

     char s[1000];
     fgets(s, 1000, stdin);
     puts(s);

и проверьте, выводятся введенные русские буквы или кракозябры?